# Sort index at a level and per partitioning by earlier levels

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I'm using pandas to count the different types or errors and correct predictions for different (machine learning) models, in order to display confusion matrices.

A particular order of the prediction and ground truth labels makes sense, for example by putting the majority class 'B' first.

However, when I sort using [`pd.DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), the other index levels are also permuted. I'd like to sort the second level per unique value of the first index.

```
errors = pd.DataFrame([
  {'model': model, 'ground truth': ground_truth, 'prediction': prediction,
  'count': np.random.randint(0, (10000 if prediction=='B' else 1000) if prediction==ground_truth else 100)}
  for model in ['foo', 'bar']
  for prediction in 'ABC'
  for ground_truth in 'ABC'

])

def sort_index(index):
  return index.map('BCA'.index)

errors.pivot(
  index=['model', 'ground truth'],
  columns=['prediction'],
  values='count'
).fillna(0).astype(int).sort_index(level=1, key=sort_index)[['B', 'C', 'A']]
```

[image: first failed attempt]

One solution is to sort by all earlier indices as well, but it's quite verbose. It's silly to have one function applied over all indices, as if they all are semantically the same. Moreover, this also rearranges the order of the models, which isn't necessarily needed. Finally it's a waste of compute in two ways: sorting smaller partitions is faster since sorting scales super-linearly, and element comparisons are slower when considering more indices.

```
def sort_index(index):
  if index.name == 'ground truth':
    return index.map('BCA'.index)
  return index

errors.pivot(
  index=['model', 'ground truth'],
  columns=['prediction'],
  values='count'
).fillna(0).astype(int).sort_index(level=[0, 1], key=sort_index)[['B', 'C', 'A']]
```

[image: cluncky soltion]

Is there a clean way to sort on higher index levels, keeping the earlier levels tied together?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the entire explanation but it seems like you want to sort at level 0, working with the assumption that level 1 is already in the order you want. If so, what about sorting using a stable sorting algorithm, such as mergesort instead of quicksort (panda's default)?

Comment: No, I consider the index as hierarchical, and hence BCA of bar should stay together, as well as the BCA of foo, but in that order. I.e. I want to sort the second level for every unique value of the first level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method.

### Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
errors = pd.DataFrame([ {'model': model, 'ground truth': ground_truth, 'prediction': prediction, 'count': np.random.randint(0, (10000 if prediction=='B' else 1000) if prediction==ground_truth else 100)} for model in ['foo', 'bar'] for prediction in 'ABC' for ground_truth in 'ABC' ])

# Pivot and reindex the dataframe
errors.pivot(
  index=['model', 'ground truth'],
  columns=['prediction'],
  values='count'
).fillna(0).astype(int).reindex(['B', 'C', 'A'], level=1)[['B', 'C', 'A']]
```

### Output:

[image]